# Need to send an Email(dynamic email address) when the checkbox is checked(True)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Need to send an email when the checkbox is checked to TRUE. For email body having the value in cell C6 and C8 and recipient email address in C7(dynamic and will change as per the user).

I tired " **MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);** ", however I failed.

I failed to get the data from the said cells and send it as a message on the recipient's email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you might want to assign the variables with a `getRange('C7').getValue()` from each of the cell. I have tested using the sample have made the message to include the assign to name and SRF number with the sample code below.

[image]

```
function sendemail(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SRF Allotment");
  const emailAddress = ss.getRange("C7").getValue();
  const name = ss.getRange("C8").getValue();
  const srf = ss.getRange("C6").getValue();
  const subject = "Email Subject";
  const message = "Hey " +  name + ",\n\n" + "Please find the SRF: " + srf + " assigned to you.";

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,message);
}
```

Would also recommend adding a button UI in your spreadsheet so you may send the email with a button on your Spreadsheet ribbon.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu

Comment: Button idea is good, but that doesn't works on mobile i guess.

Comment: If you are looking for it to apply on mobile. Maybe using a drawing a button and assigning the script to it will be better. 

Did the code work for you @AsifSheikh?

Comment: i tried all the possible way, assigning a script to image(Button) and menu, both didnt worked. the only way to trigger script is via checkbox or via dropdown. In my case checkbox seems suitable. It would be great if i find any button like object working for the phone. And Yes the code works great, Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Also is there any way to mark CC while sending the mail as per above code?

Comment: Hey @AsifSheikh yeap so what you will need to do is a add a cc in the MailApp, example:

```MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,message,{cc: "xyz@gmail.com"});```